# Duplicate xml namespace declarations php DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I use PHP `DOMDocument` to generate xml. Sometimes namespaces are declared only on root element, which is intended behaviour, but sometimes no.
For example:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$ns = "http://ns.com";
$otherNs = "http://otherns.com";
$docs = $xml->createElementNS($ns, "ns:Documents");
$doc = $xml->createElementNS($otherNs, "ons:Document");
$innerElement = $xml->createElementNS($otherNs, "ons:innerElement", "someValue");
$doc->appendChild($innerElement);
$docs->appendChild($doc);
$xml->appendChild($docs);
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->save("dom");
```

I expect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:Documents xmlns:ns="http://ns.com" xmlns:ons="http://otherns.com">
  <ons:Document>
    <ons:innerElement>someValue</ons:innerElement>
  </ons:Document>
</ns:Documents>
```

But got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:Documents xmlns:ns="http://ns.com" xmlns:ons="http://otherns.com">
  <ons:Document xmlns:ons="http://otherns.com">
    <ons:innerElement>someValue</ons:innerElement>
  </ons:Document>
</ns:Documents>
```

Why declaration of `xmlns:ons="http://otherns.com"` appears on `Document` element, but not in `<innerElement>`? And how to prevent duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy. Just add your nodes into document tree.
Additionally you can explicitly create xmlns:XXX atrtribute in root node.
See example:

```
namespace test;

use DOMDocument;

$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");

$ns = "http://ns.com";
$otherNs = "http://otherns.com";

$docs = $xml->createElementNS($ns, "ns:Documents");
$xml->appendChild($docs);

$docs->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:ons', $otherNs);

$doc = $xml->createElement("ons:Document");
$docs->appendChild($doc);

$innerElement = $xml->createElement("ons:innerElement", "someValue");
$doc->appendChild($innerElement);


$xml->formatOutput = true;

echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:Documents xmlns:ns="http://ns.com" xmlns:ons="http://otherns.com">
  <ons:Document>
    <ons:innerElement>someValue</ons:innerElement>
  </ons:Document>
</ns:Documents>
```

Comment: Please also note that DOMDocument is smart enough, so you don't need to call createElementNS() if you have namespace already declared. In my example I just use createElement() with fully-qualified element name.

Comment: You're wrong - it serializes to the same XML string only. But the element node is created outside the namespace. Output its `$namespaceURI` before you save it to XML.

Comment: The task was to simply serialize the xml to string without ns duplicates.
This task was solved correctly. So why am I wrong? ))

Comment: The comment is wrong. DOMDocument isn't "smart enough". It will not solve the namespaces if you use createElement() with fully-qualified element name - it ignores them. The created nodes are not in the namespace. Only after you serialize and parse the XML you will have valid nodes with namespaces. This is important if not just create+save the document, but have methods that work with the created DOM.